# Mysql installation freeze on MySQL Server Configuration: Type and Networking step

Tags: mysql, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install MySql on windows 7 which is in french language. When I get to MySQL Server Configuration: Type and Networking the installation freeze and it does not let me go to next step which is setting the root password. do you know how can I solve this problem. [the step that installation freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhavo.jpg)

Comment: Close the DOS windows and retry the same command again.  It happens with me on all machines I install MySQL on. The second time it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the windows text size to smaller = 100%. I had Medium(125%) before.
With 100% text size it works.